# How can I upgrade saved scikit-learn models from version 0.15.2 to 0.16.1?

Tags: scikit-learn

I have models that were created in `version 0.15.2` and saved using `pickle`.
Now I would like to upgrade to `version 0.16.1` and use the models in the new version without retraining them.

The specific classes I will need to upgrade are `PLSRegression` and `RandomForestClassifier`.

Are there helper methods for upgrading these objects in memory? If not, would appreciate information on which members changed and how the new members relate to the old ones.

Comment: found this: http://scikit-learn-general.narkive.com/IFBO486l/model-persistence-and-sklearn-version-upgrades
and this: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3590