# Model persistence in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: python, serialization, scikit-learn, pickle, jsonpickle

I am trying to save and load scikit-learn model but facing issues when the save and load are happening on different python versions.
Here what I have tried:

1. Using pickle to save a model in python3 and deserialize in python2.This works for some of the models like LR,SVM but it fails for KNN.

   ```
   >>> pickle.load(open("inPy3.pkl", 'rb')) #KNN model
   ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling
   ```
2. Also , I tried to serialize and deserialize in json using jsonpickle but getting the following error.

   ```
   data = jsonpickle.encode(lr) #lr = logisticRegression Model
   jsonpickle.decode(data)
   AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__name__'
   ```

Also, I want to know if there is some utility which I can use to serialize and deserialize scikit-learn model objects to human readable format (json,xml,protobuf etc).

Comment: I suspect this may be an issue with the pickling protocol you use. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-protocols If you are going to pickle something in python 3 and need to use it in Python 2, use `protocol=2` keyword argument in the `pickle.dump` method, which is the highest protocol understood by pickle in Python 2.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried this but getting the same error.

In python3::

     pickle.dump(neigh, open("knn_ser_py3.pkl", 'wb'), protocol=2, fix_imports=True) 
,
In python2::

    reconstructed = pickle.load(open("knn_ser_py3.pkl", 'rb'))

    ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pickling whole models, you can extract and store their coefficients.
Then load coefficients and init models with them.

Related to sklearn upgrade [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647707/how-can-i-upgrade-saved-scikit-learn-models-from-version-0-15-2-to-0-16-1). Similar approach will be valid for python versions.