# Can I safely assign to `coef_` and other estimated parameters in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

scikit-learn [suggests](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) the use of pickle for model persistence. However, they note the limitations of pickle when it comes to different version of scikit-learn or python. (See also [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38320910/5069869))

In many machine learning approaches, only few parameters are learned from large data sets. These estimated parameters are stored in attributes with [trailing underscore](https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book/blob/master/faq/underscore-convention.md), e.g. `coef_`

Now my question is the following:
**Can model persistence be achieved by persisting the estimated attributes and assigning to them later?** 
Is this approach safe for **all estimators** in scikit-learn, or are there potential side-effects (e.g. private variables that have to be set) in the case of some estimators?

It seems to work for logistic regression, as seen in the following example:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
try:
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
except ImportError:
    from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
iris = datasets.load_iris()
tt_split = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.4)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tt_split

# Here we train the logistic regression
lr = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(lr.score(X_test, y_test))     # prints 0.95

# Persisting
params = lr.get_params()
coef = lr.coef_
intercept = lr.intercept_
# classes_ is not documented as public member, 
# but not explicitely private (not starting with underscore)
classes = lr.classes_ 
lr.n_iter_ #This is meta-data. No need to persist


# Now we try to load the Classifier 
lr2 = LogisticRegression()
lr2.set_params(**params)
lr2.coef_ = coef
lr2.intercept_ = intercept
lr2.classes_ = classes
print(lr2.score(X_test, y_test)) #Prints the same: 0.95
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the estimated attributes alone is not enough - at least in the general case for *all estimators*.

I know of at least one example where this would fail.
 [`LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.transform()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/discriminant_analysis.py#L493) makes use of the private attribute `_max_components`:

```
def transform(self, X):
        # ... code omitted
        return X_new[:, :self._max_components]
```

However, it might work for some estimators. If you only need this for a specific estimator the best approach would be to look at the estimators source code and save all attributes that are set in the `__init__()` and `.fit()` methods.

A more generic approach could be to save all items in the estimator's `.__dict__`. E.g.:

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA
lda = LDA().fit([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 1], [4, 5, 6], [9, 9, 9]], [1, 2, 1, 2])
lda.__dict__
# {'_max_components': 1,
#  'classes_': array([1, 2]),
#  'coef_': array([[ -9.55555556,  21.55555556,  -9.55555556]]),
#  'explained_variance_ratio_': array([ 1.]),
#  'intercept_': array([-15.77777778]),
#  'means_': array([[ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5],
#         [ 5. ,  5.5,  5. ]]),
#  'n_components': None,
#  'priors': None,
#  'priors_': array([ 0.5,  0.5]),
#  'scalings_': array([[-2.51423299],
#         [ 5.67164186],
#         [-2.51423299]]),
#  'shrinkage': None,
#  'solver': 'svd',
#  'store_covariance': False,
#  'tol': 0.0001,
#  'xbar_': array([ 3.75,  4.5 ,  4.75])}
```

This won't be trivial for estimators that contain more complex data, such as ensembles that contain multiple estimators. See the blog post [Scikit-learn Pipeline Persistence and JSON Serialization](https://cmry.github.io/notes/serialize) for more details.

Unfortunately, this will not safely carry estimators over to new versions of scikit-learn. Private attributes are essentially an implementation detail that could change anytime between releases.

Comment: Good answer, nice counter-example and interesting mention with ```.__dict__``` which i never saw. But the title-font of that blog-link is hurting my eyes ;-)

Comment: @sascha It's probably meant to be viewed with red/blue 3D glasses :)